# How to transfer ownership during iteration?

Tags: vector, rust, iteration, ownership

I have this working code:

```
let foo_ips = vec![Ipv4Addr::new(127,0,0,1),
                   Ipv4Addr::new(127,0,0,2),
                   Ipv4Addr::new(127,0,0,3)];

let foos: Vec<Foo> = foo_ips.iter().map(|x| {Foo::new(*x)}).collect();
```

I believe that this is using a copy constructor to create new `Ipv4Addr`s to pass to `Foo::new()`.

Am I correct?

If so, how do I take the `ips` out of foo_ips to pass ownership of each to `Foo::new()`?

Comment: `Ipv4Addr` is `Copy`, so you get a copy when you do `*x`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`into_iter()`, instead of `iter()`, will consume the vector.

Note that `Ipv4Addr` is so small (32 bits) that it is `Copy` (nothing to be gained if we move instead of copying).

```rust
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(Ipv4Addr);

impl Foo {
    fn new(addr: Ipv4Addr) -> Self {
        Foo(addr)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("size of Ipv4Addr: {}", std::mem::size_of::<Ipv4Addr>());

    let foo_ips = vec![
        Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1),
        Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 2),
        Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 3),
    ];

    let engines: Vec<Foo> = foo_ips.iter().map(|x| Foo::new(*x)).collect();
    println!("engines: {:?}", engines);
    println!("foo_ips: {:?}", foo_ips); // still available

    let engines: Vec<Foo> =
        foo_ips.into_iter().map(|x| Foo::new(x)).collect();
    println!("engines: {:?}", engines);
    // println!("foo_ips: {:?}", foo_ips); // consumed!
}
```